# why are the circles with same speed appearing in the same x- coordinate

Tags: python, random, pygame

I have set up the circles so that each one of the circles have independent properties such as x, y and speed by doing this

```
    class Enemy:
            def __init__(self):
                self.x = 1300
                self.y = random.randint(10, 200)
                self.radius = random.randint(15, 30)
                self.color = (random.randint(1, 255), random.randint(1, 255), random.randint(1, 255))
                self.speed = random.randint(1, 4)
```

In the below code i am changing the speed and number of circles so that the game gets progresively harder. (note: `point1` is `time.time()` function set at the start if the code and `point2` at the end)

```
if not enemies:
            if (point2 - point1) >= 10 and (point2 - point1) <= 20:
                wave += 1
                for i in range(random.randint(1, 5)):
                    enemies.append(Enemy())
                    e.draw()
                    e.move()

            if (point2 - point1) >= 20 and (point2 - point1) <= 40:
                wave += 1
                for i in range(random.randint(8,10)):
                    enemies.append(Enemy())
                    e.draw()
                    e.move()

            if (point2 - point1) >= 40 and (point2 - point1) <= 60:
                wave += 1
                for i in range(random.randint(12, 14)):
                    enemies.append(Enemy())
                    e.draw()
                    e.move()

            if (point2 - point1) >= 60:
                wave += 1
                for i in range(random.randint(15, 20)):
                    wave += 1
                    enemies.append(Enemy())
                    e.draw()
                    e.move()



        if point2 - point1 > 20:
            Enemy().speed = random.randint(2, 6)
        if point2 - point1 > 40:
            Enemy().speed = random.randint(3, 6)
        if point2 - point1 > 60:
            Enemy().speed = random.randint(5, 6)
        if point2 - point1 > 40:
            Enemy().speed = 7
```

I think the setup is random enough although when i try to run the code, all the circles with the same speed have the same x-coordinates with different y coordinates. This gets especially obvious as more and more circles starts to spawn. What  might be causing this probelm ? Thanks

Heres my full code if anyone would like to check for reference:

```
import pygame, os, random, math, time

def main():
    point1 = time.time()

    win = pygame.display
    d = win.set_mode((1200, 600))
    win.set_caption("SHOOT")

    def write(x, y, size, writing, color):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("rage", size)
        text = font.render(writing, True, color)
        d.blit(text, (x, y))


    def collision_circle(c1, c2):
        delta_x = abs(c2.x - c1.x)**2
        delta_y = abs(c2.y - c1.y)**2
        distance = math.sqrt(delta_x + delta_y)
        if distance < c1.radius + c2.radius:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    class Player:
        def __init__(self, x, y, h, w):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.h = h
            self.w = w
            self.speed = 10
            self.hp = 10
            self.score = 0

        def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(d, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))

        def move_right(self):
            self.x += self.speed

        def move_left(self):
            self.x -= self.speed

        def boundry(self):
            if self.x <= 0:
                self.x = 0
            if self.x + self.w >= 1200:
                self.x = 1200 - self.w


    class Enemy:
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 1300
            self.y = random.randint(10, 200)
            self.radius = random.randint(15, 30)
            self.color = (random.randint(1, 255), random.randint(1, 255), random.randint(1, 255))
            self.speed = random.randint(1, 4)

        def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.circle(d, self.color , (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

        def move(self):
            self.x -= self.speed


    enemies = []

    enemies.append(Enemy())

    p = Player(600, 570, 30, 10)

    class Bullet:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.radius = 10
            self.speed = 20
            self.color = (255, 0, 0)

        def update(self):
            self.y -= self.speed

        def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.circle(d, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

    bullets = []
    wave = 1
    #bullet_append = True

    while True:

        pygame.time.Clock().tick(100)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    #while  bullet_append:
                         bullets.append(Bullet(p.x + p.w//2, p.y - 3))
                         #bullet_append = False



        d.fill((98, 98, 98))
        p.draw()
        p.boundry()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            p.move_left()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            p.move_right()

        for b in bullets:
            b.update()

            if b.y <= 0:
                bullets.remove(b)

        for b in bullets:
            b.draw()

        for b in bullets:
            if b.y <= 300:
                bullet_append = False
            else:
                bullet_append = True

        #for b in bullets:
         #   if b.y <= 300:
          #      bullet_append = True
           # else:
            #    bullet_append = False

        for e in enemies:
            e.draw()
            e.move()
            if e.x <= -10:
                p.hp -= 1
                enemies.remove(e)


        def collided():
            collided_list = []
            for b in bullets: 
                for e in enemies:
                    try:
                        if collision_circle(b, e):
                            bullets.remove(b)
                            enemies.remove(e)
                            p.score += 1


                    except:
                        pass

        if p.hp <= 0:
            while True:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        quit()

                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                            main()

                p.hp = 0    
                d.fill((98, 98, 98))
                #write(x, y, size, text, color)
                write(10, 200, 200, "GAME OVER" , (225, 0, 0))
                write(300, 400, 50, "press space to start a new game" , (225, 255, 255))
                write(200, 10, 30, "SCORE: %s"% p.score , (225, 255, 255))
                write(300, 100, 30, "WAVE: %s"% wave , (225, 255, 255))
                write(300, 50, 30, "HP: %s"% p.hp , (225, 255, 255))

                win.flip()

        point2 = time.time()

        if not enemies:
            if (point2 - point1) >= 10 and (point2 - point1) <= 20:
                wave += 1
                for i in range(random.randint(1, 5)):
                    enemies.append(Enemy())
                    e.draw()
                    e.move()

            if (point2 - point1) >= 20 and (point2 - point1) <= 40:
                wave += 1
                for i in range(random.randint(8,10)):
                    enemies.append(Enemy())
                    e.draw()
                    e.move()

            if (point2 - point1) >= 40 and (point2 - point1) <= 60:
                wave += 1
                for i in range(random.randint(12, 14)):
                    enemies.append(Enemy())
                    e.draw()
                    e.move()

            if (point2 - point1) >= 60:
                wave += 1
                for i in range(random.randint(15, 20)):
                    wave += 1
                    enemies.append(Enemy())
                    e.draw()
                    e.move()



        if point2 - point1 > 20:
            Enemy().speed = random.randint(2, 6)
        if point2 - point1 > 40:
            Enemy().speed = random.randint(3, 6)
        if point2 - point1 > 60:
            Enemy().speed = random.randint(5, 6)
        if point2 - point1 > 40:
            Enemy().speed = 7

        #write(x, y, size, text, color)
        write(10, 10, 30, "SCORE: %s"% p.score , (225, 255, 255))
        write(1050, 10, 30, "WAVE: %s"% wave , (225, 255, 255))
        write(10, 50, 30, "HP: %s"% p.hp , (225, 255, 255))    





        collided()




        win.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
    pygame.init()
    main()
```

Comment: Please read the help center article on [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening for you Enemy class is that you are starting all of the enemies at a constant x of 1300. That means that all circles with the same speed will move to the same x-coordinate. To fix this, give a random starting x-value using randint. I would try between 1300 and 1500.

Comment: Did that fix the issue?